# How to transfer username login to another view controller in object C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller login. I want to pass data username to another view controller when i login success. I use prepareForSegue. But i want to make prepareForSegue for button login. Please help me how can i do?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passSeque"]) {
        SecondView *destinative=segue.destinationViewController;
        connector *connectorClass=[[connector alloc]init];
        connectorClass.stringBeingPass =outTextField.text;
        destinative.connectClass=connectorClass;
    }

}

- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

}
```

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can connect segue from your button action through Storyboard or you can perform segue by connecting the Segue from the First View controller to the Second one, if you have connected the segue from view controller then call this method to perform the segue in your button action

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"passSeque" sender:self];
}
```

This code will trigger the segue.But make sure the segue is not connected with your button action from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Data which is used throughout your app is best managed by your app delegate. Create your own custom property in your app delegate. Then from anywhere in your code you can get access the property this way. No need to pass this stuff around!

```
[XYZAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].myCustomProperty
```